# Is Go's sql.NullString's Value predictably empty?

Tags: go

After using `db.Query` and `rows.Scan` to populate a `sql.NullString` with a `NULL` value such that its `.Valid` field is `false`, is it guaranteed that its `.String` will hold the empty string `""`?

I ask because it would be snazzy if I could use this:

```
res := ns.String
```

Instead of this:

```
var res string
if ns.Valid {
    res = ns.String
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullString

Comment: Technically it should be empty since Go strings can't be null, but prepare yourself for pain in the future if you ignore the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [current implementation](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=4428:4479#L157) yes, but the docs explicitly say to check Valid before using String. Ignore the docs at your own risk.

If you want to be safe, simply copy the type into your own package; then you know it's not going to change with the next Go release.

If you don't do that, I strongly suggest to write a test:

```
func TestEmptyNullString(t *testing.T) {
    var x sql.NullString
    x.String = "foo"
    x.Scan(nil)
    if x.String != "" {
        t.Error("string not empty after Scan")
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do the docs explicitly say that?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov, in the type documentation at https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#NullString. Note the if-statement in the example usage.